# making a tool tip, but i encounter this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleMouseIn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I get this, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleMouseIn' of undefined" in my console.log, and I am unsure as to why this happening. I can render the component correctly without having `"onMouseOver={this.handleMouseIn} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut}"` in my

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Radium, { Style, StyleRoot } from 'radium';
import ToolTip from './ToolTipComponent'

let pageStyle = {
  base: {
    "background-color": "teal",
    "width": "50px",
    "display": "inline-block",
    "float": "left",
    "height": "100%",
    "margin" : "5px"
  },
  bodyTest: {
    "padding-top": "30px"
  }
}


class BodyText extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      listItem: ['Search', 'Following', 'Browse', 'Friends']
    }
    console.log("bodyTest : ", this.state.listItem)
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={pageStyle.bodyTest}>
          <ToolTip listItems={this.state.listItem}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My component that renders the list items.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Radium, { Style, StyleRoot } from 'radium';

let componentStyle = {
  listClass: {
    "list-style-type": "none",
    "margin": "0",
    "padding": "0"
  }
};

class ToolTip extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        hover: false,
        listItems: []
      }
      this.handleMouseIn = this.handleMouseIn.bind(this);
      this.handleMouseOut = this.handleMouseOut.bind(this);
    }

    handleMouseIn() {
      this.setState({ hover: true })
    }

    handleMouseOut() {
      this.setState({ hover: false })
    }

    render() {
      const tooltipStyle = {
        display: this.state.hover ? 'block' : 'none'
      }

      let itemListNodes = this.props.listItems.map(function(item){
          return <div><li onMouseOver={this.handleMouseIn} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut}>{item}</li><div class={tooltipStyle}>{item}</div></div>
      })

      return (
        <div>
          <ul style={componentStyle.listClass}>{itemListNodes}</ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default ToolTip;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that using `this.` inside `.map` is not having the result you want. What you need to do is supplying `this` as the second parameter of your `.map`, like so:

```
let itemListNodes = this.props.listItems.map(function(item){
  return <div><li onMouseOver={this.handleMouseIn} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut}>{item}</li><div style={tooltipStyle}>{item}</div></div>
  }, this)
```

Also, you need to change `<div class={tooltipStyle}>` to `<div style={tooltipStyle}>`

Comment: By the way, what also would work is using arrow notation for your map function: `let itemListNodes = this.props.listItems.map(item => (<div>...</div>));`